# Umbraco 7.4.3 keep redirected to install when deploy as virtual directory

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, umbraco7, virtual-directory

I have developed a website for a client using Umbraco 7.4.3 and the website has filled with content and ready to go live. My client deploy this website under a subfolder of their own main domain, likes `domain.com/newsite` with virtual directory method on IIS. notes: main site is also umbraco.

When the new site accessed, it always redirected to /install just like the first-time installer wizard when we just deploy original Umbraco, though it keeps loading forever and not showing anything. I already found similar problem (deploy as subfolder/virtual directory) and following solution provided, but didn't find one exactly like my case. When I tried on my local machine (other than development one), I couldn't reproduce the problem.

I wonder what setting or configuration did Umbraco used to tell it to run installer?
all *.config and database used exactly the same except connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

When I check umbracos log file (located in `App_Data\logs\`) there is a database connection error. It seems that Umbraco checking version to database to determine whether it was first run or not.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was because I was inadvertently pointing my live web config at another of my Umbraco websites that used a different version of Umbraco - took a while to spot because there were no clues in the log files.